# How to call Database Class in Expression Engine?

Tags: php, expressionengine

I started to learn Expression Engine.

I want to get some data from the database. How do I have to use the database class to achieve that?

I would be glad to get a very detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site for details of data base related doubts regarding Expression Engine.

[Database class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html)

**Selecting the active recod**

```
    $query = ee()->db->select('username,email,mobile_number')
    ->from('members')
    ->get();
```

**It’s highly recommended that you use CodeIgniter’s Active Record because queries will be easier to read and edit
**

Comment: @user3505678 : Did u tried with the coding mentioned for calling the db class .?